# how to access default browser history in android?

Tags: android, android-browser

i am trying to access default `browser(chrome)` history in android but cannot get any result.
i want to access history(url) and want to show `url` in `listview`. i have also included 
I took help from this [website](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-get-browser-history-in-android.html)
below is my code

activity_main.xml

```
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  </ListView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                int itemPosition = position;

                String itemValue = (String) listView
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : "
                                + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }    });
    }



    public void getBrowserHist() {

        Cursor mCur = managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        mCur.moveToFirst();
        if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {

                String s = mCur.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX);
                values.add(s);
                mCur.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Chrome most likely stores this information in a different location than Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI.

Comment: no @RobbyPond . https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#BOOKMARKS_URI . it appears it stores them under the same `Uri` :)

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu No, The default Browser app may store it there but I mean that the Google Chrome app most likely doesn't store that information there.

Comment: but he said "default browser(chrome)" ... chrome is default from KitKat or some recent version...